# Nopcommerce registering new shops

Tags: shopping-cart, shopify, nopcommerce

In shopify if I create a new store I get my own admin panel. I am going through nopcommerce and it appears to me that a single installation is built for only one shop admin. So if I am running nopcommerce from my site I can not let users register and create new stores - I could run 1 store though?
Is this understanding correct or nopcommerce lets users register and create new shops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding nopCommerce. It's not a SaaS platform like Shopify, but a full on-site installation of an ecommerce application.

In recent versions, you can manage more than 1 store with the same installation, so that different domains point to different stores. However, in my opinion this is intended to have different shops under the same owner, so you don't have to set up another server/hosting plan for each shop you want to run.

When having multiple stores, you can assign products, categories and so to a specific store.

See more information at http://www.nopcommerce.com/featurelist.aspx

Quote from above:

> With multi-store support you can launch several online stores using a single integrated system. You can create unique online stores for multiple brands, products, B2B, B2C, affiliates, co-branded stores and more. You can also quickly launch micro-stores for promotional campaigns. Best of all, every online store shares a single database.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly the info I was looking for.